# Evaluate an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate:

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin^3(x-\frac{1}{x} )^5}{x^3} dx$$

I've been stumped by this Integral and cannot think of how to evaluate it. 
I substituted $\dfrac{1}{x^2}=t \Rightarrow \dfrac{-dt}{2}= \dfrac{dx}{x^3}.$ 
$$$$However, I can't understand what to do next. $$$$Any help on solving this would be truly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: First of all, are you sure that it can be done, and that it gives an explicit result not involving weird special functions? Mathematica 7 was unable to compute it.

Comment: For sure the integrand function does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$. Perhaps neither it is improperly Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Sir, I saw this problem in a worksheet. The question required us to show by evaluating that the integral was $0.$ Sir, I thus cannot guarantee that the question is correct.

Comment: It seems it is equal to $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{96} (3^{3/5} - 9) \sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac75\right)
\approx -0.15356212695352349
$

Comment: @MakeaDifference: maybe the intended trick was to split the integration range as $(0,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$ and apply the substitution $x\to\frac{1}{y}$ in the second integral. However, we must check in advance that we are allowed to do so. And probably we are not, depending on the notion of integrability you are assuming.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio it is improper Riemann integrable, the singularity $\frac{1}{x^3}$ get cancelled by the oscillating piece $\left(\sin\left(\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^\color{red}{5}\right)\right)^3$.

Comment: @math110 split the integral to $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, change variable to $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$ and then combine it with the integral on $(1,\infty)$. Finally, change variable to $u = (x-\frac{1}{x})^5$. The integral then becomes $-\frac15 \int_0^\infty \sin^3(u) u^{-3/5} du$ which WA knows how to integrate.

Comment: we have $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{t^3}-t\right) \sin^3{\left(t-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^5}dt $$  then can't have following your result

Comment: @math110 $\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{d(t - \frac{1}{t})}{t + \frac{1}{t}}$

Answer (score 3):

The integral is Riemann improper integrable. To save the argument that whether it converges or not. Let us look at following integral as a function of cutoff $\Lambda$.

$$I(\Lambda) \stackrel{def}{=}\int_{1/\Lambda}^\Lambda 
\sin^3\left[\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right] \frac{dx}{x^3}
= \left(\int_{1/\Lambda}^1 + \int_1^\Lambda\right)
\sin^3\left[\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right] \frac{dx}{x^3}
$$
Change variable to $\displaystyle\;t = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x},& x < 1\\x, & x > 1\end{cases}$ and notice for $x \in (0,1)$,

$$\frac{dx}{x^3} = -tdt\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sin\left[\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right] = 
-\sin\left[\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)^5\right]$$
We have

$$I(\Lambda) = \int_1^\Lambda \sin^3\left[\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)^5\right]
\left(\frac{1}{t^2} - t^2\right) \frac{dt}{t}$$

Using the fact $\displaystyle\;\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{d(t - \frac{1}{t})}{t + \frac{1}{t}}\;$, we get

$$I(\Lambda) = -\int_1^\Lambda \sin^3\left[\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)^5\right]\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right) d\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)$$

Change variable to $\displaystyle\;u = \left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)^5$, we find

$$I(\Lambda) = -\frac15 \int_0^{\left(\Lambda - \frac{1}{\Lambda}\right)^5} \sin^3(u) u^{-3/5} du$$

Since the function $\int_0^u \sin^3(t) dt$ is uniformly bounded for $u$ over $(0,\infty)$ and the factor $u^{-3/5}$ is monotonic decreasing to $0$ as $u \to \infty$. By  [Dirichlet's test on improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals), following limit exists
$$\lim_{X\to\infty} \int_0^X \sin^3(u) u^{-3/5} du$$
This means the original integral exists as a Riemann improper integral and equal to
$$\lim_{\Lambda\to\infty} I(\Lambda) = -\frac15\int_0^\infty \sin^3(u) u^{-3/5} du$$

The last integral is something WA understand. If you throw this to WA or just look at math110's answer, the integral we want is equal to

$$\frac{1}{96} (3^{3/5} - 9) \sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac75\right) \approx -0.15356212695352349$$

As a double check, one can ask WA to evaluate the original integral numerically and it reproduces above number. 
If one want to picky, one can use a different upper bound and lower bound for the cutoff but the final answer remains the same.

Comment: Hello,at last integral can using well known result to find by hand.

Comment: @math110, I am lazy ( I don't want to justify the last formula ).

Comment: me too, nice +1

Answer (score 3):

as @achille hint,I have post it
since
$$I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\sin^3{(x-\frac{1}{x})^5}}{x^3}dx=(\int_{0}^{1}+\int_{1}^{\infty})\dfrac{\sin^3{(x-\frac{1}{x})^5}}{x^3}dx=I_{1}+I_{2}$$
since
$$I_{2}=-\int_{0}^{1}x\sin^3{(\dfrac{1}{x}-x)^5}dx$$
so
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^3}-x\right)\sin^3{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^5}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)\sin^3{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^5}d\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
let $x-\dfrac{1}{x}=t$,then 
$$I=-\int_{0}^{+\infty}u\sin^3{u^5}du=-\dfrac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin^3{u}u^{-\frac{3}{5}}du=-\dfrac{1}{20}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(3\sin{u}-\sin{3u})u^{-3/5}du$$

and use well known result
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin{x}\cdot x^pdx=\cos{(\pi p/2)}\Gamma{(1+p)},-2<p<0$$
can find it.becasue
$$-\dfrac{3}{20}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin{u}\cdot u^{-\frac{3}{5}}du=-\dfrac{3}{20}\cos{\dfrac{6\pi}{5}}\Gamma{(\dfrac{2}{5})}$$
we know 
$$\cos{\dfrac{6\pi}{5}}=-\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$
and other is simaler